# ¿Como centrar Cards con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, angular

Resulta que tengo el siguiente problema con cards-columns de bootstrap 4

**mi codigo es el siguiente:**

```
<div class="container m-5">
    <div class="card-columns m-5 animated fadeIn mx-auto">
      <div class="card puntero" *ngFor="let item of items" (click) = "verArtista(item)">
        <img src="{{item.images | noimage}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.name }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" *ngFor="let artista of item.artists">{{artista.name}}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este codigo esta contenido en la clase container por lo que las cards terminan alineadas a la izquierda similiar al siguiente ***ejemplo***

> [image: ejemplo_cards]

He intentado algunas configuraciones pero ninguna parece funcionar.

Comment: Agrega las configuraciones que has intentado y que no te han funcionado, por favor

Comment: en realidad lo puedes centrar poniendo ese `mx-auto` en el container , así, 
`<div class="container m-5 mx-auto">`

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez, Hola amigo tu configuracion fue correcta Gracias, "habria jurado que habia intentado con esa clase tambien".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo como utilizas un container tu Cards no ocupan el 100% de ese container te recomiendo utilizar un **row** y después a las cards aplicarles el tamaño respetando el sistema de 12 columnas que utiliza la grilla de bootstrap partiendo de ahí te dejo un ejemplo donde utilizo tres cards dentro de un fila (*row*) que asu vez esta dentro de un container, al principio deberián aparecer justamente igual que tu ejemplo, pero utilizando flex podemos alinearlas al centro de manera vertical con **justify-content-center** esta clase la aplicamos en el div que contiene la clase row debido a que el comportamiento de este se aplica a los hijos del contener padre.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
         <div class="card col-lg-3" >
             <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-lg-3" >
             <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-lg-3" >
             <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
 </div>
```